# How to apply functions to a subset of the data in a vectorized manner

Tags: r

**Question:**

How to apply functions to a subset of the data in a vectorized manner.

**Example:**

For the data frame below:

```
x=c(1,2,1,2,1,2)
y=c(3,4,5,4,3,2)
df=data.frame(x,y)
```

I would like to apply a function (i.e. min()) to all y values for each of the x value, and collect it in a vector.

Basically, I would like to have a vectorized version of this:

```
nb = max(x);
V = rep(0.0, nb)
for(i in 1:nb){
    v = df [ x == i,  ]$y;
    V[i] <- min(v);
}

# basically here:
# V[1] = min( df$y for x=1)
# V[2] = min( df$y for x=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `tapply` is designed for such problems:

```
with(df,tapply(y,x,FUN=min))
#1 2 
#3 2
```

If you want to add the results to your data frame, you can use the function `ave`:

```
df$group.min <- with(df,ave(y,x,FUN=min))
#   x y group.min
# 1 1 3         3
# 2 2 4         2
# 3 1 5         3
# 4 2 4         2
# 5 1 3         3
# 6 2 2         2
```

Comment: The 'tapply' function is technically a loop, but I agree that a loop is probably necessary for this task.

Comment: Add an `unname(...)` in there to get the desired output.